# SVN Complete Backup from Code Vault

Tags: windows-server-2008, svn, visualsvn-server

Am maintaining the SVN code in Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, There are more than 100+ repositories are maintained in the server and i need to back it up. Yes there is a way by svnadmin hotcopy to backup each repository but i need to backup all the repositories in a single command. I heard there is a way doing it but i could not reach up. Please someone explain me with the command how to do this way.

Thanks,
Hudson

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just doing a conventional backup on the volume(s) in which the repositories reside?  That should capture all you need to recover in an emergency.